# WTB: dual band HT that can adapt to assistive hearing devices

Tags: ht, disability

I am returning to ham radio after many decades away and Iʻm looking for an HT that will mimic my iPhone. My cellphone, via bluetooth, connects to both of my hearing aids (via a branded hearing aid app) and all audio is delivered directly to my hearing aids. Is there a way I can connect my hearing aids to a new handheld rig? Iʻve searched the topics on this list and find nothing about hearing assisted devices.

n.b. The hearing aids are Jabra Enhance Pro PM RIC (receiver-in-canal) rechargeables. The iPhone/Android app for Jabra devices has advanced features available only for iPhones, but the iPhone needs to be connected to the Internet. That limitation is not acceptable. I need a standalone hearing solution that relies on what I can carry with me.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and welcome back to the hobby! Can you share the specific model of hearing aid you have? This will enable more specific and helpful answers. Also, can you share your country? FYI, this site does not support wanted ads or transactions, but I think it's easy to interpret your post as, "Hey, here's what I need, does this kind of thing exist in the market" and folks will hopefully answer it as such.

Comment: Thanks webmarc. I have a pair of Jabra hearing aids which are paired to my iPhone through a Jabra app. The app also allows signals from a TV-connected device that also channels TV signals to my hearing aids as well. I live in Honolulu BTW. When I have talked to the vendors of the hearing aids ( a Big-Box store) they are unfamiliar with anything beyond what they offer, so Iʻm at a loss as to which direction to go; do I try to find a solution through the hearing aid manufacturer or see whatʻs available on the handheld market?

Comment: When you share details, please edit your question rather than putting them in a comment. Comments are not searchable.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome back!

Yaesu & Icon both sell HT models that feature bluetooth capability, though they may only be able to connect to one aid at a time depending on the model of aids that you have.

Another (fairly pricey) option is the RFinder radio which actually incorporates and android phone and radio together...and which may be able to natively run the app for your hearing aids.

### Important note:

The model you mention (Jabra Enhance Pro PM) appear to use an accessibility related BT Profile (which makes sense!) as opposed to the Hands Free Profile most BT headsets implement. I wouldn't be surprised to find that the Icon & Yaesu models won't pair with your aids, but that the RFinder will.

I'd recommend testing this with a fellow ham's equipment before committing to a purchase.

Comment: Iʻve seen both the Yaesu and Icom ads, but it appeared to me as thought the bluetooth connectivity was limited to programming memory and data settings. Iʻm not that knowledgeable about bluetooth protocols to know exactly what it means when a vendor says that their product has bluetooth connectivity.

Comment: they both have Bluetooth audio support as well… I have personal experience with both. Additionally both manufacturers sell Bluetooth headsets as accessories for those HTs.

Comment: Thx for the encouragement! I just visited the RFinder website and glad that I was sitting down when I saw the pricing. If I hadnʻt retired a dozen or so years ago I might be tempted to try one of their products. I havenʻt met any Honolulu ham operators yet, so perhaps I might find one who has a Yaesu or Icom that I could try.

Comment: Updated answer with additional info referencing your specific aids.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem.  The Jabra Enhances Pro R is hamstrung (no pun) in that the internal t-coil is unavailable for communication.